# Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following query in PHP using PDO:

```
$form = $_POST;
$alias = $form[ 'alias' ];
$nombre = $form[ 'nombre' ];
$pass = $form[ 'pass' ];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbmeseros ( alias_mesero, nombre_mesero, pass_mesero ) VALUES (:alias,:nombre,:pass)";
}
$query = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute(array(':alias'=>$alias,':nombre'=>$nombre,':pass'=>$pass) );//THIS IS LINE 92
```

but I get a warning:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /.../NuevoAdminMeseros.php on line 92
```

And i don't see the reason for the warning, there are three variables on both statements, I think.

Comment: Check your code carefully for typos. You'll get this error if the `:parameters` in the SQL don't match the array keys in `execute()`.

Comment: @Barmar, I have learnt from the previous question, and may be there are typos in my code, but in this case I am not able to find them. i have checked the form, the query and the array keys, and I don't find any typo there. But i will check it again now. Thank you in any case.

Comment: A lone } is a parse error. Since the code isn't failing as a parse error that means the partner { (and condition statement) isn't in the question. Seems likely that `$sql` wasn't the insert statement in the question when the error was encountered, or some similar "how could anyone else see that?" error - because the code in the question was insufficient to explain the problem, and misleading. -1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (PDO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961772/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined-pdo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$form = $_POST;
$alias = $form['alias'];
$nombre = $form['nombre'];
$pass = $form['pass'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbmeseros (alias_mesero, nombre_mesero, pass_mesero) VALUES (:alias,:nombre,:pass)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':alias' => $alias,':nombre' => $nombre,':pass' => $pass));
```

Comment: I have tried your proposal and I get the same error. I have checked it also with only one param, and the same error is shown. Thank you.

Comment: the warning doesn't disappear, when after clicking the submit button, the form data are stored in the database. Any advice to remove the warning message?.

Comment: @AD7six, you are right. I have unchecked the answer, I have found the issue, it was the } before the prepare statement. Thank you

Comment: @AD7six i didnt get u

Comment: @fortune, sorry for my error. All is working now. It was just a typo.

Comment: @mvasco great to hear your problem is solved. +1 for your self debugging.

Comment: @AD7six, everything is OK now, no need to go further. It was my fault not detecting the typo. I have got a down vote for that, that's enough for now. And thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @fortune, thank you too. But someone considers I deserve a down vote. Doesn't matter. Thank you again.

Comment: @mvasco Stupid peoples will down vote. Without even reading the complete context.

Comment: thank you again, and don't waste more time with his question any more...have a nice day